# how can i add new row my react bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I created the table I mentioned below using React js. When I click on the button below the table, I want to add a new row to the table. I have listed the react code I wrote below. how can I do that?

**My React Code**

```
const PPP13 = (props) => {
    return (
        <Jumbotron>

            <p className="btn-group">13- List all owners of 20% or more of the equity of the Applicant</p>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Owner Name</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Ownership %</th>
                    <th>TIN (EIN, SSN)</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <FormControl aria-label="DDD"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <FormControl aria-label="DDD"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <FormControl aria-label="DDD"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <FormControl aria-label="DDD"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <FormControl aria-label="DDD"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </Table>
        <Button className="btn-group" name="add" value="No">
            Add more owners
        </Button>
        </Jumbotron>
    )
}
```

Comment: a) keep table data in an array in `state` b) rewrite JSX so it renders the state array instead of hardcoded `<tr>`s. c) append to array

Comment: Did you mean to add new table data when you press the button?

Comment: i mean new row .

Comment: @ChrisG please show me how can i do that

Comment: Here you go: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do. Lets say you have a Main component which will get all details.

```
class Products extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //  this.state.products = [];
    this.state = {};
    this.state.filterText = "";
    this.state.products = [
      {
        id: 1,
        category: 'Sporting Goods',
        price: '49.99',
        qty: 12,
        name: 'football'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        category: 'Sporting Goods',
        price: '9.99',
        qty: 15,
        name: 'baseball'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        category: 'Sporting Goods',
        price: '29.99',
        qty: 14,
        name: 'basketball'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        category: 'Electronics',
        price: '99.99',
        qty: 34,
        name: 'iPod Touch'
      }, {
        id: 5,
        category: 'Electronics',
        price: '399.99',
        qty: 12,
        name: 'iPhone 5'
      }, {
        id: 6,
        category: 'Electronics',
        price: '199.99',
        qty: 23,
        name: 'nexus 7'
      }
    ];

  }

  handleAddEvent(evt) {
    var id = (+ new Date() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)).toString(36);
    var product = {
      id: id,
      name: "empty row",
      price: "mpty row",
      category: "mpty row",
      qty: 0
    }
    this.state.products.push(product);
    this.setState(this.state.products);

  }

  handleProductTable(evt) {
    var item = {
      id: evt.target.id,
      name: evt.target.name,
      value: evt.target.value
    };
var products = this.state.products.slice();
  var newProducts = products.map(function(product) {

    for (var key in product) {
      if (key == item.name && product.id == item.id) {
        product[key] = item.value;

      }
    }
    return product;
  });
    this.setState({products:newProducts});
  };
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <ProductTable onProductTableUpdate={this.handleProductTable.bind(this)} onRowAdd={this.handleAddEvent.bind(this)} products={this.state.products} />
      </div>
    );

  }

}
```

This contains the code for adding row.Then for the table do something like this.

```
class ProductTable extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var onProductTableUpdate = this.props.onProductTableUpdate;
    var product = this.props.products.map(function(product) {
      return (<ProductRow onProductTableUpdate={onProductTableUpdate} product={product}  key={product.id}/>)
    });
    return (  
      <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={this.props.onRowAdd} className="btn btn-success pull-right">Add</button>
        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>price</th>
              <th>quantity</th>
              <th>category</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {product}

          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
    );

  }

}
```

Now for the row Comoponent:

```
class ProductRow extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <tr className="eachRow">
      <td>
        {this.props.product.id}
      </td>
      <td>
        {this.props.product.price}
      </td>

       <td>
        {this.props.product.qty}
      </td>
       <td>
        {this.props.product.category}
      </td>
      </tr>
    );

  }

}
```

**Working Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/mrAhmedkhan/nvgozjhy/

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's my plan:

First we create a state to hold all the data for the table. I've used an object instead of an array as it's much easier to do the change handling. With arrays you always end up doing all this awkward splicing. You can always parse the object out into an array when you're ready to use it elsewhere.

Then we render out each row of the table by mapping over the entries in our table state. Note we also write the change handler inside the map, meaning we can easily use the rowId (tableData key) to set our new state when a change comes in.

Finally we plop in a button to add more rows. This has a click handler associated with it (`handleAddRowClick`) which counts the number of rows we have and uses this to generate a new rowId. We use the new rowId to expand the tableData state to include a new `defaultRow`. I defined `defaultRow` outside of the function, this prevents it from being redeclared on every render.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Table, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap'

const defautRow = { colA: '', colB: '' }

const IncreasableTable = props => {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState({
    row1: { colA: '', colB: '' }
  })

  const handleAddRowClick = () => {
    const extantRowsCount = Object.keys(tableData).length

    setTableData(s => ({
      ...s,
      [`row${extantRowsCount}`]: defautRow
    }))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Table>
        {
          Object.entries(tableData).map(([rowId, data]) => {
            const handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
              setTableData(s => ({
                ...s,
                [rowId]: {
                  ...s[rowId],
                  [name]: value
                }
              }))
            }
            return (
              <tr key={rowId}>
                <td>
                  <Input name="colA" value={data.colA} onChange={handleChange}/>
                  <Input name="colB" value={data.colB} onChange={handleChange}/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          })
        }
      </Table>
      <Button onClick={handleAddRowClick}>Click me to add more rows</Button>
    </>
  )
}

export default IncreasableTable
```